# Random Exeception error. System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a C# website and I just started getting some random errors over the previous weekend. The error is being generated from random pages on the site, and of course, there is hardly any information to go on. Here's the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2.AddKey(TKey key, TItem item)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2.InsertItem(Int32 index, TItem item)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
  at CommerceBuilder.Catalog.DefaultUrlRewriter.InitializeCache()
  at CommerceBuilder.Catalog.DefaultUrlRewriter.a(String A_0)
  at CommerceBuilder.Catalog.DefaultUrlRewriter.RewriteUrl(String sourceUrl)
  at CommerceBuilder.Services.b.c(Object A_0, EventArgs A_1)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I've read a bunch of articles on similar errors, but I haven't added any new dictionary items that I know of, so I'm not sure where to start. Can anyone please give me some suggestions?

Comment: What is `CommerceBuilder`?  What is the operation which is resulting in this error?

Comment: Something is trying to add a key to a `Dictionary` and that key already exists. I would look at `CommerceBuilder.Catalog.DefaultUrlRewriter.InitializeCache()` for a start.

Comment: CommerceBuilder is the AbleCommerce eCommerce platform

Comment: Try using `ConcurrentDictionary` and `TryAdd`

Comment: i would check the CommerceBuilder class and take a look at the "initialize" method. If you are not able to see it ( it is written into a third party assembly) then i would contact that third party provider or i would try to decompile it using a tool.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing can happen when two threads are simultaneously attempting to add an entry to a dictionary that is not thread safe.

If you have the ability to modify the code that is raising the error, I would suggest using a [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a System.Collections.Dictionary.

Comment: I don't have any way to modify the way that part of the code works.

Comment: You may need to game your site so that only one thread is running during initialization.  E.g. if you have a test client, have it crawl the site off-hours, with only one client thread-- and make sure your app pools are set not to reset themselves automatically.  Perhaps contact your vendor for further advice.